# Javascript function to control opacity on click

Tags: javascript

i want to make a function to control opacity when an  is clicked. i have this and it didn't work

```js
var op = function(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "1";
};
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/71fb624cb4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="home h" id="h" onclick="op(" h ")"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a>
    <a class="home acc"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></i>Account</a>
    <a class="home fli"><i class="fas fa-fighter-jet"></i>Flights</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If you want to make element transparent, then you should set 0, not 1

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the id quotes, if you are not passing a JS variable in it like this for example: `"op("+h+")"`, then use single ones or escape it like other question suggested:

```
onclick="op('h')"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Always check the error console.** Don't just assume things should work.

You have invalid HTML, which in turn is leading to a JS syntax error when your onclick happens.

```
onclick="op("h")"
```

You can't have quotes within quotes - how would the parser know which related to what? Instead you need to escape the inner ones with `\` or just use single quotes.

```
onclick="op(\"h\")"
onclick="op('h')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onclick` attribute. If you were styling the links, you could do the following:

```js
document.getElementById("h").style.opacity = 1;

function changeOpacity(el) {
  el.style.opacity -= 0.1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script
    src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/71fb624cb4.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <script src="js.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="home h" id="h" onclick="changeOpacity(this)"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a>
    <a class="home acc"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></i>Account</a>
    <a class="home fli"><i class="fas fa-fighter-jet"></i>Flights</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```